# In STL map with structure as value, destructor of the structure gets called twice

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct, std, stdmap

I am having a `std::map` with 'int' as key and a custom struct as value. When I access a key, it creates the key and value (as expected) but the value's ctor gets called once and at the same time it's dtor gets called twice. I am finding it's really weird.

Example:

```
struct stStruct
{
    int some_value;
    stStruct()
    {
        some_value = 10;
        printf("\nCame in stStruct c'tor");
    }

    ~stStruct()
    {
        some_value -= 10;
        printf("\nCame in stStruct d'tor");
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Map of <int, struct> 
    std::map<int, stStruct> MyIntStructMap;
    MyIntStructMap[0]; // stStruct ctor called once and dtor twice
    MyIntStructMap[0]; // neither stStruct ctor nor dtor called
    printf("\nValue of some_value in stStruct %d", MyIntStructMap[0].some_value);
    // Expected -10 above as dtor was called twice
}
```

And the output is:

```
Came in stStruct c'tor
Came in stStruct d'tor
Came in stStruct d'tor
Value of some_value in stStruct 10
```

This is really frustrating. Especially if am having pointers in the struct and allocate deallocate memory in it's ctor and dtor respectively, the code crashes (as deletion over same pointer happens twice).

Moreover, I do not understand despite the code `some_value -= 10;` being called twice, how the value of `some_value` in above example still remains `10`?

I am using VS2010 on Windows.

Comment: -ve voter please care to mention the reason?

Comment: "The constructor" is misleading. Classes have *many* constructors.

Comment: I am referring the 'struct' value's c'tor (which is only one stStruct() in above example)

Comment: @Andrew The struct also has a compiler-generated copy constructor since you didn't provide one. If you do that, you will solve the mystery.

Comment: @ molbdnilo: Did not get you. Please can you elaborate how is it causing this problem? Also, not sure why all -ve votes :-(

Comment: You should have do it this way: `stStruct a, b, c; MyIntStructMap[0] = a; MyIntStructMap[1] = b; MyIntStructMap[2] = c;`

Comment: @Andrew: Every class has a (possibly implicitly declared) copy constructor, and sometimes also a move constructor.

Comment: When I do MyIntStructMap[0], it should simply 'construct' its value and insert the element in the map. I don't understand why should value construction need to be invoked multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because the compiler generated c-ctor is being executed during the map accessing using l-value index operator.

check this code

```
struct stStruct
{
   int some_value;
   stStruct()
   {
       some_value = 10;
       printf("\nCame in stStruct c'tor");
   }

   stStruct(const stStruct& oOrg)
   {
       some_value = oOrg.some_value;
       printf("\nCame in stStruct copy c'tor");
   }

   ~stStruct()
   {
       some_value -= 10;
       printf("\nCame in stStruct d'tor");
   }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   // Map of <int, struct> 
   std::map<int, stStruct> MyIntStructMap;
   MyIntStructMap[0]; // stStruct c'tor will be called once and d'tor will be called   twice
   MyIntStructMap[0]; // stStruct c'tor or d'tor won't be called
   printf("\nValue of some_value in stStruct %d", MyIntStructMap[0].some_value); // As d'tor was called twice, ideall it should print value -10

   return 0;
}
```

generates:

```
Came in stStruct c'tor
Came in stStruct copy c'tor
Came in stStruct copy c'tor
Came in stStruct d'tor
Came in stStruct d'tor
Value of some_value in stStruct 10
```

Comment: I can see. But why copy c'tor is being called twice here?

Comment: When I do MyIntStructMap[0], it should simply 'construct' its value and insert the element in the map. Key here is simple integer. I don't understand why should value construction need to be invoked multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for hint. **Learning: When we use structure as a value in STL map, and if the structure has pointer members in it (being freed in destructor) we _must_ define our own copy constructor for the structure and we should take care of copying pointer allocations in it (so that destructor would not free original pointer)**